# Biblioteca para carregar mapas customizados?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

Eu estou procurando um componente que trabalhe como o *Google Maps* (navegação e zoom) onde eu possa carregar meu próprio mapa. É um mapa bem simples.

Eu achei o *mAppWidget* mas encontrei poucos exemplos de implantação e me bati um pouco para entender o componente.

Se alguém já tiver trabalhado com algo parecido e puder me ajudar, ficarei agradecido.

Comment: Veja este link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling

Answer (score 1):

Use o [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com), lá você tem uma biblioteca completa de personalização do seu mapa, inclusive, para Android e Web, ele tem uma plataforma dentro do site para setar as cores do mapa, e também tem modelo prontos.
Veja esse [link com um tutorial](http://www.thiengo.com.br/iniciando-com-mapbox-android-sdk-parte-1).